FATAL Error: [config validation of [elasticsearch].preserveHost]: definition for this key is missing in kibana
FATAL  Error: [config validation of [elasticsearch].preserveHost]: definition for this key is missing
How to fix this error in kibana ?
I have added elasticsearch.preserveHost: false in the kibana.yml.it didnt work.
Could you please let me know.
